# Jquery replace all strings starting with # and add link

Tags: jquery, str-replace

I have a large blocks or text on a message board that will contain strings beginning with #. Can I use jquery to replace these with a link containing the string?

For example, changing:

```
<div id="mydiv">This is my #block of text with #multiple hash strings</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="mydiv">This is my <a href="newpage.asp?block">#block</a> of text with <a href="newpage.asp?multiple">#multiple</a> hash strings</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following code to replace strings:

```
var string = "#has etc #has ";
string = string.replace(/#(\S+)/g, '<a href="newpage.asp?$1">#$1</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work:

```
$('*:contains("#")').each(function(){
 if($(this).children().length < 1) 
      $(this).html( 
           $(this).text().replace(
                /#(.*)#/
                ,'<a href=newpage.asp?'+$(this).text()+'>'+$(this).text()+'</a>'
           )  
       ) 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's always a good idea to test your solutions before posting them, possibly on http://jsfiddle.net , to make sure they actually work as intended.

Comment: You should be consequent when replacing content using `text()` and `html()`. If the html contained `&gt;script&lt;`, the result after replacing would be `<script>`.

Comment: Thanks @RobW does the &gt;script&lt; effect also happen with html()? Just tried and it seems ok. http://jsfiddle.net/bobney/4tKn3/

Comment: @Bobney Your code does not work at all, because the div element contains a child. Even if you're only using `.html()`, the code is susceptible to errors: `<a style="color:#000">Color</a>` will break.

Comment: @RobW ah, you're not wrong. Will go and play. Thanks for putting me on the right road.